# "ssh: connect to host myserver port 22: Invalid argument" (intermittent, ipv6, link-local address, dhcp hostname)

Tags: dhcp, linux, ssh, dhcpv6

Since this question is off-topic I moved it to Super User. But I was unable to delete it.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1349197/ssh-connect-to-host-myserver-port-22-invalid-argument-intermittent-ipv6-l) is the new location.

Here is the original question:

---

I'm trying to connect to a headless server via my laptop; they share a wired link via a Linksys wireless router ("Linksys EA6350") and TP-Link ethernet switch. I'm running Arch Linux on both machines, using a pretty default Systemd setup with dhcpcd for the network configuration.

I recently experienced the following error when trying to ssh to the server:

```
$ ssh -v -v -F /dev/null myserver
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /dev/null
debug2: resolving "myserver" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myserver [fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf] port 22.
debug1: connect to address fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf port 22: Invalid argument
ssh: connect to host myserver port 22: Invalid argument
```

Running the same with `strace` shows the error comes from `connect`:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(22), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Usually I have a local `named` forwarding DNS queries but the error persists when I go back to using the router's DNS server directly:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

The error is intermittent: every few minutes I am able to connect successfully. When I can connect successfully, I see that `connect` is using an IPv4 address:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(22), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.149")}, 16) = 0
```

However, the `host` command shows the same IPv4 address whether the connection is working or broken:

```
$ host myserver                   
myserver has address 192.168.1.149
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260003/connect-returns-invalid-argument-with-ipv6-address) question I thought to specify the interface manually (`ssh -v -v -F /dev/null -B en0 myserver`). This eliminates the error when it occurs, but it is not a permanent solution for me and it doesn't explain why the error suddenly appeared.

Comment: Sadly host configuration is off topic here. You can try asking on[su].

Comment: OK that's confusing, I come to the main page of this site and register and I see a header with "Questions   Tags   Users   Badges   Unanswered   Ask Question". I look around wondering how I can figure out if this is the right place to ask, and eventually I give up and just decide that other similar questions are in the list of questions so it must be OK. But I was supposed to scroll down to the very bottom and click tiny "Help" and then click on "What topics can I ask about here?", OK I got it. Can someone help me migrate this to Super User? Sorry for the trouble...

Comment: I'm going to copy-paste into a Super User question and then delete this one, unless someone objects.

Comment: I wasn't able to delete it because it already has an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever is doing hostname resolution is returning link-local IPv6 address(es) that aren't valid for the interface selected -- i.e. "any". Link-local addresses must specify the interface -- eg. fe80:...:1%eth0

Why you're getting a link-local address is unknown. Perhaps people familiar with Arch linux could provide further assistance.

(Also, `ip -6 [route|addr|...]` is apparently necessary to see IPv6 information on your system)